# Add username on createUserWithEmailAndPassword in Firebase with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I want to add the username on the signup of the user and I am using the following code:

```js
//Create Account With Email&Password
    const createUser = (email, password, username) => {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(() => {
            updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                displayName: username,
            });
        });
    };
```

This is my useEffect in the same js file

```js
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect');
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
```

This code is adding the displayname successfully, but when I redirect to my account page the displayname is not directly showing up and I am getting a memory leak warning from the router-dom. Is there a cleaner and better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the account page loads before firebase loads the auth data, you can use something like

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user)=>{
    if(user){
        getUserName = auth.currentUser.displayName;
        // Load the rest of the page
    }
}
```

at your redirected user page,assuming you are using the right auth state, which you can refer from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?authuser=0

Comment: I fixed it so the username will show up with a latency of a few milliseconds but I still run into the memory leak warning. I added async await to the updateProfile function.

Comment: So I assume that memory leak is happening from the page after you redirect, can you show the code as well?